# Depth first drawing left or right

Tags: depth-first-search

I am supposed to draw a deapth first tree starting with the F node. This tree is based on the matrix below. This tree is suppoed to be drawn when the kode "visit" works as follows:

```
  void visit (int k) // DFS, adjaceny matrix
    {
    int t;
    val [k] = ++id;
    for (t = l; t<= V; t++)
    if (a[k][t] ! = 0)
    if (val[t]== unseen) visit (t);
    }

                        | A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
                      --|--------------------------
                      A | 1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
                      B | 1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
                      C | 0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
                      D | 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
                      E | 1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1
                      F | 1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
                      G | 0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
                      H | 1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0
                      I | 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
```

the answer to the question is this:

```
                     ......F......
                     : :   :\    :
                     : :   : A   :
                     : :   :/ \  :
                     : :   H   E :
                     : :  /:    \:
                     : : D :     B
                     : :/  :
                     : G...:
                     :/
                     C
```

but my question is: What determins wheter to place A to the left or right of the F node? I can draw this tree correct, but the LEFT RIGHT is where i go wrong, any opinions about what determins to place A to the left, E to the left B to the left of E and so on?

Comment: Not to sure about the answer, but I'm pretty sure your tree is wrong. Because assuming A=1 and your variable V = One above I. then surely the first value that you would visit once you are in A would  be B?

Comment: If the nodes are not weighted, it does not matter where you place them. Placing a node to the right or left is meaningful when you have e.g a node weighted tree. Like @JayDev, I think the output tree is wrong.

Comment: This is a copy of the exam answerws from last year, i have a similar task on my exam in about 10 hrs but i cant seem to figure out why the / goes to the left and \ to the right, because the right (higher) and left (lower) seems to not count in this tree as far as i see..